# Submitting a secondary form when clicking PayPal button

Tags: html, button, paypal, forms

I have been having trouble trying to capture form data when using a PayPal button.

My setup is that I have a form with contact details (name, address, etc.) and a PayPal "Buy Now" button to register for an event. What I would like is to click the PayPal button, and also POST the first form to a different .php address. I have tried putting an onclick attribute on the PayPal button that submits both forms, but that only ended up submitting the PayPal form.

How might I get this working with this example code?

```
<form id="myForm" action="externalsite.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" size="20" name="fullName" id="fullName_id" />
</form>

<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" id="paypalForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="9CQULDDB593EC">
    <table>
        <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Registration">Registration</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
        <option value="Event Fee">Event Fee $10.00 USD</option>
        </select> </td></tr>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="image" src="RegisterButton.jpg" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" onclick="getInputValues()">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("input[name='submit']").click(function() {
  $("#myForm").submit();
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hold the default event until you are done with doing whatever you want with the input values , I assume you want to save them, there might be some better solution but this might help.

```
var submitted = false;
$('input[name=submit]').click(function(e){
    if(submitted = false){
         e.preventDefault();
         var form_values = $('#myform').serialize();
         $.ajax({
         url:'save.php',
         type:'POST',
         data: form_values
         success : function(response){
               submitted = true;
               $('input[name=submit]').click();
         }
        });
    }

});
```